# Basins of attraction for Newton-Raphson fractal colouring

Tags: fractals, chaos-theory, newton-raphson

What's the general strategy/approach for defining the basins of attraction within the Newton-Raphson(NR) function in the complex plane? I would like to understand where these are to colour-in a NR fractal.  I hear that's its possible to discover basins by iterating some number of times around a point- but what if there are thousands of points? would I have to run the model twice (once for basin inference and then again for the plot?).

For example:-

(a) What are the (two) basins of attraction for: $f(z) = \frac{z^2 - 1}{2z}$

(b) How did you arrive at them?

Forgive me if I sound stupid- I know full well that I am no mathematician.

Comment: I trust you're aware that these basins of attraction can be extremely complicated, e.g., see http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/mandelset/complexnewton/newtonbasins/Basins3.html Here's an exposition with some code: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s997-introduction-to-matlab-programming-fall-2011/basic-plotting/basins-of-attraction/

Comment: Thanks very much Gerry, I'll have a look!

Comment: As @GerryMyerson points out, the basins of Newton's method generally have very complicated boundaries. For rational functions of degree two (like yours) however, Newton's method will converge to the closer of the two roots. As your roots are $\pm 1$, the basins of attraction are the open left and right half planes.

Comment: @MarkMcClure thanks very much.